# What's with NSIS namespaces?

Tags: installation, include, nsis

#### Edit: As of now all the header I am including is `MUI.nsh`. I think that should rule out the option of having LogicLib.nsh and Section.nsh included by some other parts of the script.

#### And the code compiles still in spite of having the scripts I posted below.

Ok I called those parts of the NSIS script that look like `!include MUI2.nsh` namespaces. I need a little more clarity on which are the namespaces that I really should `!include` in my code. Here are my confusions:

1) I have codes like this:

```
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
Page custom DbPage "" ": Information Page"
Page instfiles
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
```

which basically means I am using a custom InstallOptions page as well. So I thought I need to include `!include InstallOptions.nsh` and `!include MUI.nsh`. It works. But to my surprise even if I am not including `!include InstallOptions.nsh` the code compiles, and I see no difference in end result !! But if I am including  only `!include MUI2.nsh`, the code doesn't compile. But it compiles and works normally if I include `!include MUI2.nsh & !include InstallOptions.nsh`. **So what should I include, `!include MUI.nsh` alone or a combo of `!include MUI2.nsh` & `!include InstallOptions.nsh` ??** . The code compiles if I include all `!include MUI2.nsh`, `!include InstallOptions.nsh` and `!include MUI.nsh`. **In that case, the macros and functions will be loaded from `!include MUI2.nsh` or `!include MUI.nsh` ??**

2) I use a [function defined here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Show_custom_page_when_a_section_has_been_selected) to see if a section is selected or not like this:

```
SectionGetFlags ${Section_Name} $R0 
IntOp $R0 $R0 & ${SF_SELECTED} 
IntCmp $R0 ${SF_SELECTED} show
```

The link asks to include `!include Sections.nsh`, but for me the script compiles even without including that. **Why is it?? Should I ideally `!include` it?**

3) I have code like:

```
${If} ${FileExists} `$0\*.*`
${Else}
    CreateDirectory $0
${EndIf}
```

and

```
  ${If} $2 != <
    StrCpy $2 >
  ${EndIf}

  ${If} $3 != <
    StrCpy $3 >
  ${EndIf}
```

etc. **So shouldn't I `!include` `LogicLib` ?** I get the code compiled even without using `!include LogicLib`.

Why is that I am able to compile NSIS script without including appropriate packages/references?

**Update:** I got an [answer here](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=346607) as well for the same question in nullsoft's official forum. That tells the same story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call them namespaces, NSIS does not have [namespaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace_%28computer_science%29). `!include`'ed files are "pasted" directly into the code (at the point where the !include line is).

**1)**

MUI2 uses nsDialogs for its custom pages and MUI(v1) uses InstallOptions.

If **you** need the macros in InstallOptions.nsh in **your** code then **you** should include it. If the MUI needs it then it will include it without you having to do anything.

You should **not** include both MUI2.nsh and MUI.nsh, you need to pick one of them!

**2)** and **3)**

Some other code included Sections.nsh/LogicLib.nsh already. It does not hurt to include it again and it is a good idea to do so (So that you don't depend on code you don't control to include it).

Comment: Hi Anders, My script is fully working, and compiles with no warning, no errors. The confusion I am having is, it compiles in many possible ways of including headers. So I know `if I need macros of InstallOptionsnsh then I should include it`. Though I am using an ini file to show a custom page, my code compiles and works perfect even if I dont include InstallOptions.nsh. So my question now is should I include MUI alone or combo of MUI2 and InstallOptions. I suppose the latter since I think MUI2 is better than MUI or it makes no difference?

Comment: Regarding 2) and 3), this is just a doubt. I have no where in my code included `sections.nsh` or `logiclib`, yet it compiles. You say some other code must have included them. How is it possible? Could you suggest an example? Can headers be auto-included from some part of the code? The headers I use (for now) is just MUI.nsh!!

Comment: LogicLib ( http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Include/LogicLib.nsh ) includes sections.nsh because it implements ${SectionIs*} and MUI probably includes the LogicLib...

Comment: @Anders Why is it not a namespace? Also is there any documentation on :: operator in NSIS?

Comment: @Pyjong The :: is not really a operator, it is used to separate the dll name from the function name when using plug-ins.